# another or the other?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say A accounts for 60% of the total, B accounts for **another** 30% and C accounts for **the other** 10%. If I express it the way below, should I use **another** or **the other**?

> A accounts for 60% of the total. B and C account for **another/ the
> other** 30% and 10% respectively.

Comment: It must **the other** to refers to **the** remaining 40% .

Comment: As it it happens, the *total* of B and C is **the** remaining ("the other") 40%, but ***respectively*** means each of the two percentages actually referenced is just ***another*** 30% and ***another*** 10%. Note that the text still needs ***another,*** just as it would if we changed 30% to, say, 25%, leaving 5% unaccounted for.

Comment: ...The first sentence of your question *could* end with ***another** 10%.* That's effectively a "stylistic choice", since by the time we get to *...and C accounts for...* we know that the amount remaining is 10%.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @FumbleFingers, why does "we know that the amount remaining is 10%" mean that "another" could be used?

Comment: You've got that the wrong way round! It's not that knowing that the amount remaining is 10% means that ***another*** could be used. You can *always* use ***another*** in such contexts. But knowing that the amount remaining is 10% means that ***the other*** could be used!